# DFBeta Measures for Subsets of Variables

Tags: regression, logistic, outliers

I need to calculate the DFBETA statistics for a logistic regression. The number of columns in the $X$ matrix is $3000$ and the number of records is in the millions. I've been using R's `dfbetas()` function which this takes a very long time. I'm primarily interested in $10$ variables so is it possible to quickly calculate the DFBETAs for that subset only, instead of for the whole $X$ matrix?